# Ionic Components not working in the framework

Tags: ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I have set up ionic environment

1) `node` and `npm`

2) `cordova` and `ionic` with `sidemenu` template

While using the `ionic` 4 components in the application its classes are not working

[image]

You can see it shows button without css.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Components are working, I can see `<ion-content>` and `<ion-header>` in the console. probably you css is not working , try this in html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button class="btn">My button</button>
</ion-content>
```

and in scss

```
.btn{
        background: red;
 }
```

you can change the css property it this **btn** class and it should reflect when running the app

Comment: customize css works but inbuilt css like class secondary or primary won't work

Comment: Is it the case with ionic 4 only?